# AsyncTasks will not fire until I leave an Activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I don't get this, and it's really frustrating me.

All of my long-running operations happen in `AsyncTask`s.  For example, the user interacts with the app somehow and an item is added to a list.  This causes an `AsyncTask` to fire, the data to be written to an sqlite3 database, and then the list is refreshed.

I've recently bumped my Android support up from 2.3.3 to 4.0.  I've created a new 4.0 emulator and, for some reason, all of my `AsyncTask`s seem to queue up and only fire once the user leaves the screen!

Why is this happening????

The code is pretty simple.  I'm not doing anything interesting here.  For example, here's an `AsyncTask` fire example:

```
Log log = data.mFoodLog;
log.setUserId(getUserId());
log.setDay(mBeginningOfToday.getTimeInMillis()/1000);
log.setStatus(DbDefinitions.STATE_POSTING);

(new SaveLogTask()).execute(new SaveObjectTaskParams(getApplicationContext(), log));
```

The debugger shows this code being executed.  I have another breakpoint inside the `doInBackground()` method, but that breakpoint never gets hit until I leave the screen.  I've also put `Log.e` messages around this code and ran it without the debugger to make sure the debugger isn't doing anything weird.  `doInBackground()` **never** gets fired until I leave the `Activity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first sight seems to be what @Cliffroot says, an async task not ending and queuing the ret of them (due to the behaviour changes in Android).

To execute them on diferent threads use: `asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);`

Answer (score 1):

Basically the behaviour of `AsyncTask` has changed since version `3.0`. On `2.3.3` it used to execute `AsyncTasks` concurrently, but now it does it sequentially.
So your problem might be that you have one `AsyncTask` that does not finish, and because of that fact the others don't even start (it's hard to say without seeing more of your code).

Comment: What exactly is the logic behind them making this change?  `AsyncTasks` then only seem to be async in that they do not operate on the main thread.  I had no idea about this.  Unless there's some really good reason that is traveling over my head, I'm honestly a bit upset about it.

Comment: When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.

Taken from developer.android.com

Comment: Here's where I'm confused:  My Android device is running 4.1 and this behavior doesn't happen.  My `AsyncTasks` fire immediately even though I have a background `AsyncTask` that spins the life of the `Activity` (or rather, between `onResume` and `onPause`).